# Stop processing a http POST request if it is larger than x size

Tags: go

If I have a basic http handler for POST requests, how can I stop processing if the payload is larger than 100 KB?

From what I understand, in my POST Handler, behind the scenes the server is streaming the POSTED data.  But if I try and access it, it will block correct?
I want to stop processing if it is over 100 KB in size.

Comment: [Here](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#LimitReader) are docs for LimitReader

Answer (score 11):

Use [http.MaxBytesReader](https://godoc.org/net/http#MaxBytesReader) to limit the amount of data read from the client. Execute this line of code

```
r.Body = http.MaxBytesReader(w, r.Body, 100000)
```

before calling r.ParseForm, r.FormValue or any other request method that reads the body.

Wrapping the request body with [io.LimitedReader](https://godoc.org/io#LimitedReader) limits the amount of data read by the application, but does not necessarily limit the amount of data read by the server on behalf of the application.

Checking [the request content length](https://godoc.org/net/http#Request.ContentLength) is unreliable because the field is not set to the actual request body size when chunked encoding is used.

Comment: Yikes, totally missed `http.MaxBytesReader` although it's there from (at least) Go 1.0! Thanks, need to update some of my LimitedReader use cases now.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can simply check `http.Request.ContentLength` param to know about the size of the posted request prior to decide whether to go ahead or return error if larger than expected.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but in case you didn't read @Cerise's answer: _Checking the request content length is unreliable because the field is not set to the actual request body size when chunked encoding is used._